# Can i get A&P course materials in .pdf format?

Tags: faa, icao, airframe-and-powerplant

I would be very grateful if you provide me any material about A&P basic course for mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

Go here for the PDF material.

[Aircraft Handbooks & Manuals](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aircraft/)

Comment: thank you, but any other? i'm looking for materials being taught in academies

Comment: https://www.kingschools.com/aviation-courses/mechanics

Comment: I have friends who are currently in or have recently graduated from Aviation Institute of Maintenance. My local A&P shop has Jeppesen Maintenance Textbooks. Since the written knowledge tests come from the official FAA material, any school curricula that I have seen pretty well mirrors the FAA books. When it comes time to actually take the written test, I believe I will opt for the King School online curriculum. Then again, A&P for me will be just a hobby to work on my own plane. PS If you choose self-study in the US, you will have to document time actually working in a shop to get certificated

Comment: ,grateful to you